# Making a div appear based on selection

Tags: javascript

First of all I have never really played with Javascript before, asides finding stuff that you clever types have created and then adding it to my sites.

I would like to show a div based on which option is selected in a drop down on the page.

I have Tariffs 1 - 4, the Tariff selected shows as t1, t2, t3 and t4 but the Divs are then not becoming visible.

I have tested the show / hide function of the div bit with a simple button and that worked, I just can't seem to make it pick up the variable to show the one which is selected.

```
<div>
                                Value Selected: <span id="current"></span>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <select id="select" name="options">
    <option>Choose Your Option</option>
    <option value="t1"> 1</option>
    <option value="t2"> 2</option>
    <option value="t3"> 3</option>
    <option value="t4"> 4</option>
</select>   
                            <div class="t1"><p>Tariff 1</p></div>
                            <div class="t2"><p>Tariff 2</p></div>
                            <div class="t3"><p>Tariff 3</p></div>
                            <div class="t4"><p>Tariff 4</p></div>
                        </div>
```

```
function showSelectedItem() {
    var item = document.getElementById("select").value;
   document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = item;
    
    if (item.style.display === 'none') {
    item.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    item.style.display = 'none';
  }
    
}

document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", showSelectedItem);
```

then the css for all the t1, t2... divs is

.t1
{display: none}

Thanks in advance, I suspect its something very obvious when you know what you are looking at.

Comment: can you please share working fiddle

Comment: As you can see, the displaying of t1, t2 etc works, but the Divs all stay hidden

https://jsfiddle.net/k33npx/cbe36aq5/

Comment: you are to apply item.style.display on selected dropdown value. which is invalid . you need to use it on div with selected dropdown class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youe css styles wont be avaliable with `item.style.display`. Only the inline styles will be available with the above selector.

Logic

- Make all nodes hidden initially with `style="display:none"` in HTML
- On change, check the selected value.
- Hide all nodes with class name which is not same as selected value.
- If you want to hide the dropdown when the user selects an option, you could select the dropdown with `document.getElementById("select")` and set `style.display = 'none'`

```js
function showSelectedItem() {
  var item = document.getElementById("select").value;
  document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = item;
  const classes = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'];
  // Toggle visibility;
  classes.forEach((classNode) => {
    document.querySelector(`.${classNode}`).style.display = classNode === item ? 'block': 'none';
  });
  // Hide the dropdown when the user selects an option
  document.getElementById("select").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", showSelectedItem);
```

```html
<div>
  Value Selected: <span id="current"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select id="select" name="options">
    <option>Choose Your Option</option>
    <option value="t1"> 1</option>
    <option value="t2"> 2</option>
    <option value="t3"> 3</option>
    <option value="t4"> 4</option>
  </select>
  <div class="t1" style="display: none;">
    <p>Tariff 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="t2" style="display: none;">
    <p>Tariff 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="t3" style="display: none;">
    <p>Tariff 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="t4" style="display: none;">
    <p>Tariff 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the css styles also to be reflfced with your script, you have to make use of `Window.getComputedStyle()` [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
function showSelectedItem() {
  var item = document.getElementById("select").value;
  document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = item;
  const selectedNode = document.querySelector(`.${item}`);
  if (selectedNode) {
    const displayValue = window.getComputedStyle(selectedNode).display;
    const classes = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'];
    classes.forEach((classNode) => {
      document.querySelector(`.${classNode}`).style.display = classNode === item ? 'block': 'none';
    });
    // Hide the dropdown when the user selects an option
    document.getElementById("select").style.display = "none";
  }
}
document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", showSelectedItem);
```

```css
.t1, .t2, .t3, .t4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Value Selected: <span id="current"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select id="select" name="options">
    <option>Choose Your Option</option>
    <option value="t1"> 1</option>
    <option value="t2"> 2</option>
    <option value="t3"> 3</option>
    <option value="t4"> 4</option>
  </select>
  <div class="t1">
    <p>Tariff 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="t2">
    <p>Tariff 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="t3">
    <p>Tariff 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="t4">
    <p>Tariff 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thats great, thanks so much.

I have also just added the drop down box to the classes, so that once you make a selection it hides itself as I don't want people clicking around from Tariff to Tariff.

Thanks again!

Comment: @PaulKeen So do you want to hide the select tag once the user select an option? Is this supposed to run only once?

Comment: Yes I am hoping to build this up so that when someone picks "Tariff 1" they then get shown various pieces of information that is specific to that Tariff on all of the web pages, but do not then flick to the other Tariffs to confuse themselves. So my next step is to try and make this a session? So the selection stays for all the time they have the web page open. Then resets for the next visit. But baby steps and all that

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution here

1.) Add **t-content** class to you t1 - t4. This is easily to hide them in javascript later on.

```
.t-content {
    display: none
}

<div class="t1 t-content"><p>Tariff 1</p></div>
<div class="t2 t-content"><p>Tariff 2</p></div>
<div class="t3 t-content"><p>Tariff 3</p></div>
<div class="t4 t-content"><p>Tariff 4</p></div>
```

2.) Slight modify your javascript code

```
 function showSelectedItem() {
    var item = document.getElementById("select").value;

    document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = item;

    // Select our target
    var selected_div = document.getElementsByClassName(item)[0];

    // Make all t-content hide first
    var t_content = document.getElementsByClassName('t-content');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < t_content.length; i++) {
        t_content[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Display our target div
    selected_div.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare display property of div instead of value of dropdown.

```
var item = document.getElementById("select").value;
var dv = document.querySelector("."+item);
document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = item;

if (dv.style.display === 'none') {
    dv.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    dv.style.display = 'none';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/palak6041/9wj07ebv/17/

This will not hide other divs though you need to hide it with additional code

below example will hide other div, only selected div will be visible

https://jsfiddle.net/palak6041/9wj07ebv/25/